# Find biggest contour even if it's not closed (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have such an image with contours
[image]

And when I'm looping through the contours like

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    ### Here I'm showing each contour on the image
```

I can't get the biggest contour of all the document, I think it's because it isn't closed. So is there any way to get that contour?

Comment: Well strictly speaking, that isn't a contour.

Comment: If word "contour" affects your understanding of my question, I'll change it.

Comment: it does not. I'm only saying that it is reasonable that a contour finder does not find the contour, because in a *strict* sense, this is not a contour.

Comment: Ok, could, please, advice some another OpenCV instrument to solve my issue?

Comment: @vZ10 you are trying to find contour with cv2.RETR_LIST which return all contour, you can try with cv2.RETR_TREE which always give you outer contour